# How to set Gemfile for the need of different computer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I have a rails app that need to be install on two computer (mac and linux)

somehow the mac can run the rails app with ruby-mysql gem and the linux can run with mysql gem

How do I set the bundle Gemfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the mysql2 gem in this case, otherwise there are tricks to install different gems based on the environment, however you will encounter annoyances when pulling from the repository since you will have to run bundle install (or update) everytime if Gemfile.lock is in your repo (it should)

```
gem "mysql2", "~> 0.2.7"
```

Platform example:

```
if RUBY_PLATFORM.downcase.include?("darwin")
  gem "rb-fsevent"
  gem "growl"
end
```

Comment: so i put the condition in gem.lock?

Comment: no, the Gemfile.lock should stay untouched since it's generated automatically.

Answer (score 1):

MacOS and Linux work fine with gem 'mysql' or 'mysql2'. it's just written on C++ and cross-platform

Comment: use: **gem 'mysql', '2.8.1'**   OR  **gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.2.7'**

Comment: still need find another solution? does it help you?